# autocompleteinput is blank when I go to edit screen for the first time. This happens repeatedly

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

When I go to the edit screen for the first time autocomplete is blank there. But when I come back again its populated. The code is like this:

```
<Edit {...props}>
<SimpleForm>
    <ReferenceInput label="Author" source="authorId" reference="authors">
        <AutocompleteInput optionText="name" />
    </ReferenceInput>
</SimpleForm>
</Edit>
```

Comment: Which version of admin-on-rest are you using ?

Comment: "admin-on-rest": "^1.3.2",

Comment: We just released version `1.4.0`. Can you try with it and let us know ?